# How to create a generic object for an interface?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I am writing a method which fetch data from SQL Server which returns a `DataTable`.

I want to create many different classes which represent database entities and a base `BaseObj` class which contains no objects but a static method which converts data conversion logic from `DataRow` to an object for each class.

```
[Route("api/GetClassA")]
[HttpPost]
public List<DerivedA> GetDerivedA()
{
    return ApiConsumer("DerivedA")
}

public List<DerivedA> GetDerivedB()
{
    return ApiConsumer("DerivedB")
}

public static List<iObject> ApiConsumer(string ApiName)
{
    var dataTable = SomeDataTableAccessCaller(ApiName);

    List<iObject> returnList = new List<iObject>();

    foreach(DataRow dataRow in dataTable)
    {
        iObject temp = new iObject();
        temp.DataTableConversion(dataRow);
        returnList.Add(temp);
    }

    return returnList;
}

public class DerivedA : iObject
{
    string name;
    int age;

    public void DataTableConversion(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        name = dataRow["name"].ToString();
        age = int.Parse( dataRow["age"].ToString());
    }
}

public class DerivedB : iObject
{
    string name;
    string address;

    public void DataTableConversion(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        name = dataRow["name"].ToString();
        address = dataRow["age"].ToString();
    }
}

public interface iObject
{
    public void DataTableConversion(DataRow dataRow);
}
```

I know you can't create an object of an interface

```
iObject temp = new iObject();
```

But how can I achieve this in order to save me a lot of code for the foreach iteration and the duplicated object initiation logic above?

I tried to use virtual method of a class, but I cannot convert `iOBject` back to derived classes to return back to the API methods.

Note: I don't want to use `ExpandoObject` or any dynamic programming, because I need to serialize my strongly typed objects to Json.

Comment: If you using the DataTable as an intermediary, I'd suggest not using it and instead read directly into the typed object you want.

Comment: `public static List<T> ApiConsumer<T>(string ApiName) where T : iObject, new()`

Comment: what does new() mean at the end? I don't have any generic C# programming experience. It seems quite daunting to me. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the type of object you want created based on the datarow,
you can do this as follows:

```
namespace mynamespace;

public interface Imain{...}
public class One:Imain{...}
public class Two:Imain{...}


DataRow dr = ...

Type newtype = Type.GetType(dr["mytype"]);  // "Namespace.Object" is safer
Imain newobj = (Imain)Activator.CreateInstance(newtype);  // can also pass arguments 

// or could use logic
Imain myobj = dr["decidingfield"] switch
{
    "One" => (One)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(One)),    
    "Two" => (Two)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Two)),
};
```

Comment: not sure how it works and what Activator is. i think it's a completely different approach

Comment: iObject temp = new iObject();
becomes
iObject temp = (iObject)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DerivedA));

Comment: i need to study about this Activator library. I thought I needed to use Generic <T>?

Comment: I realise the code above solve me another part of problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I worked out my solution with Generics.
Here is the solution:

```
[Route("api/GetClassA")]
[HttpPost]
public List<DerivedA> GetDerivedA()
{
    return ApiConsumer.ApiAconsumerMethod("DerivedA")
}

public List<DerivedA> GetDerivedB()
{
    return ApiConsumer.ApiAconsumerMethod("DerivedB")
}

public class ApiConsumer<T> where T: iObject, new()
{
public static List<T> ApiAconsumerMethod(string ApiName){
    var dataTable = SomeDataTableAccessCaller(ApiName);

    List<T> returnList = new List<T>();

    foreach(DataRow dataRow in dataTable)
    {
        T newObj= new T();
        newObj.DataTableConversion(dataRow);
        returnList.Add(newObj);
    }

    return returnList;
}
}

public class DerivedA : iObject
{
    string name;
    int age;

    public void DataTableConversion(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        name = dataRow["name"].ToString();
        age = int.Parse( dataRow["age"].ToString());
    }
}

public class DerivedB : iObject
{
    string name;
    string address;

    public void DataTableConversion(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        name = dataRow["name"].ToString();
        address = dataRow["age"].ToString();
    }
}

public interface iObject
{
    public void DataTableConversion(DataRow dataRow);
}
```